# How to order data from firebase database in a spinner?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

I have a firebase database that has a name and number in it for each of my stores. I want a spinner to show the names of each store so we can select one. the store name example is "0023 franklin", and i want to order them by the number.

my code to make the spinner is

```
    mydb.orderByValue().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Is better to use a List, because you don't know the size
            // of the iterator returned by dataSnapshot.getChildren() to
            // initialize the array
            
            final List<String> areas = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Store storeName = areaSnapshot.getValue(Store.class);
                areas.add(storeName.getStoreName());
            }

            Spinner areaSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            ArrayAdapter<String> areasAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(checkout.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, areas);
            areasAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            areaSpinner.setAdapter(areasAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

it shows all the stores but doesn't order them by the number. and the stores are not added in the database in order.

how to i make this happen?

adding JSON

storelist:

-KvIoZC0AbpD1-SJJrIS

faxNum: 987654321

storeName: 0024 Franklin

-KvIobgHLouocLpMkN6k

faxNum: 1234567890

storeName: 0003 Randle

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a snippet of the JSON you're trying to display? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following methods to sort the data:

> orderByChild()
>
> orderByValue()
>
> orderByKey()

You can store that number with a key like **'storeNumber'** and use the available method like:

```
orderByChild("storeNumber");
```

for more usage refer to :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data?authuser=0#sort_data

Comment: so where would i add that to my code? i can't seem to get it to work

Comment: Use mydb.orderByValue("storeNumber").addValueEventListener();